# Spheres random motion without overlap in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, overlap, packing

I want to move multiple times randomly a list of ~1 millions spheres.
I have an initial list of non-overlapping spheres (array of centers) with the same radius.

Therefore, the goal is to apply small translations to each of them, taking care that, at the end, the spheres are still within some space boundaries, but also that no overlap occurs.

I tried myself to do it, by moving one by one the spheres and rejecting the motion if there is an overlap. However, even only testing for neighbors, the script is incredibly slow and would take hours just for N_motions=1.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def in_cylinder(all_points, Rmax, Zmin, Zmax):
    all_points = np.atleast_2d(all_points)
    radial_distances = np.sqrt(all_points[:, 0]**2 + all_points[:, 1]**2)
    return (radial_distances <= Rmax) & (Zmin <= all_points[:, 2]) & (all_points[:, 2] <= Zmax)

def move_spheres(centers, r_spheres, motion_coef, N_motions):
    n_spheres = len(centers)
    updated_centers = np.copy(centers)
    motion_magnitude = motion_coef * r_spheres

    # Identify potential neighbors for each sphere
    for _ in range(N_motions):
        tree = cKDTree(centers)
        potential_neighbors = [tree.query_ball_point(center, 2*r_spheres + 2*motion_magnitude) for center in updated_centers]
        updated = np.zeros(n_spheres, dtype=bool)
        for i in range(n_spheres):
            # Generate a random direction
            direction = np.random.randn(3)
            direction /= np.linalg.norm(direction)

            # Generate a random magnitude
            magnitude = np.random.uniform(0, motion_magnitude)

            # Move the sphere
            new_center = updated_centers[i] + direction * magnitude

            # Check for space boundaries
            if in_cylinder(new_center, Rmax, Zmin, Zmax):
                neighbors_indices = [idx for idx in potential_neighbors[i] if idx != i]
                neighbors_centers = updated_centers[neighbors_indices]
                distances = np.linalg.norm(neighbors_centers - new_center, axis=1)
                overlap = np.any(distances < 2 * r_spheres)

                # Update the center if no overlap
                if not overlap:
                    updated_centers[i] = new_center
                    updated[i] = True
                    print(f'{sum(updated)}/{i+1}')
            else:
                print('out of cylinder')
        print(sum(updated), sum(updated)/n_spheres)
    return updated_centers
```

Would you have any recommendations to speed this up?

Comment: For one, you can skip the `sqrt`s if you deal with squared distances instead of distances alone.

Comment: You don't want to build the `KDTree` every time you move.  Building a tree with a million items takes time.  Have you actually instrumented to this to figure out where the time is being spent?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. The vast majority of the time spent is:                 `distances = np.linalg.norm(neighbors_centers - new_center, axis=1)` and `overlap = np.any(distances < 2 * r_spheres)`.

As for the KDTree, I believe we need to re-calculate it every time we have tried to move all spheres once, in order to reset the list of potential problematic neighbors.

I am not sure how I can make that faster, but I need at least a factor >100 improvement to make this practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a set of optimizations that add up to about a ~5x improvement, depending on how you benchmark it. I don't think a 100x improvement is possible without completely changing the algorithm.

I tried the following ideas to improve this:

- Avoid running tree.query_ball_point() in a loop. query_ball_tree()
  accepts an array of points, and it is nearly always faster to query
  with the whole array rather than loop over the array. This is about 3x faster.
- Use the multicore mode of tree.query_ball_point(). This gave about a 30% speedup.
- Profile and use numba to replace hotspots. I wrote functions that use
  numba to compute the parts that seems to be slow when run under
  line_profiler.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import numba as nb
import math

@nb.njit()
def in_cylinder(all_points, Rmax, Zmin, Zmax):
    radial_distances = all_points[0]**2 + all_points[1]**2
    return (radial_distances <= Rmax ** 2) & (Zmin <= all_points[2]) & (all_points[2] <= Zmax)


@nb.njit()
def generate_random_vector(max_magnitude):
    # Generate a random direction
    direction = np.random.randn(3)
    direction /= np.linalg.norm(direction)

    # Generate a random magnitude
    magnitude = np.random.uniform(0, max_magnitude)
    return direction * magnitude


@nb.njit()
def euclidean_distance(vec_a, vec_b):
    acc = 0.0
    for i in range(vec_a.shape[0]):
        acc += (vec_a[i] - vec_b[i]) ** 2
    return math.sqrt(acc)


@nb.njit()
def any_neighbor_in_range(new_center, all_neighbors, neighbors_indices, threshold, ignore_idx):
    for neighbor_idx in neighbors_indices:
        if neighbor_idx == ignore_idx:
            # This neighbor is myself - ignore this one
            continue
        distance = euclidean_distance(new_center, all_neighbors[neighbor_idx])
        if distance < threshold:
            return True
    return False


def move_spheres(centers, r_spheres, motion_coef, N_motions):
    n_spheres = len(centers)
    updated_centers = np.copy(centers)
    motion_magnitude = motion_coef * r_spheres

    # Identify potential neighbors for each sphere
    for _ in range(N_motions):
        tree = cKDTree(centers)
        potential_neighbors_batch = tree.query_ball_point(updated_centers, 2*r_spheres + 2*motion_magnitude, workers=-1)
        updated = np.zeros(n_spheres, dtype=bool)
        for i in range(n_spheres):
            vector = generate_random_vector(motion_magnitude)

            # Move the sphere
            new_center = updated_centers[i] + vector

            # Check for space boundaries
            if in_cylinder(new_center, Rmax, Zmin, Zmax):
                neighbors_indices = np.array(potential_neighbors[i])
                overlap = any_neighbor_in_range(new_center, updated_centers, neighbors_indices, 2 * r_spheres, i)

                # Update the center if no overlap
                if not overlap:
                    updated_centers[i] = new_center
                    updated[i] = True
                    # print(f'{sum(updated)}/{i+1}')
            else:
                # print('out of cylinder')
                pass
        print(sum(updated), sum(updated)/n_spheres)
    return updated_centers
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks! It is already a good improvement